# Error shown while generating barcode for pdf in jasper report using jaspersoft studio

Tags: jasper-reports, barcode

I am getting error while generating barcode in jrxml file which will be converted to jasper file .

I am using jaspersoft studio to implement the barcode.

But while implementing i am facing the below errors.

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when
>   compiling

report expressions class file:

```
com.keepdynamic.barcode.generator.jasperreports.BarcodeRenderer cannot be resolved to a type
value = new com.keepdynamic.barcode.generator.jasperreports.BarcodeRenderer(
com.keepdynamic.barcode.generator.jasperreports.BarcodeFactory.createLinear(
8,"((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRenderable)field_barcode.getValue())")); 
//$JR_EXPR_ID=152$
com.keepdynamic.barcode.generator.jasperreports.BarcodeFactory cannot
be resolved to a type
value = new com.keepdynamic.barcode.generator.jasperreports.BarcodeRenderer(
com.keepdynamic.barcode.generator.jasperreports.BarcodeFactory.createLinear(
8,"((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRenderable)field_barcode.getValue())")); 
//$JR_EXPR_ID=152$
com.keepdynamic.barcode.generator.jasperreports.BarcodeRenderer cannot
be resolved to a type
value = new com.keepdynamic.barcode.generator.jasperreports.BarcodeRenderer(
com.keepdynamic.barcode.generator.jasperreports.BarcodeFactory.createLinear(
8,"((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRenderable)field_barcode.getOldValue())")); //$JR_EXPR_ID=152$
                        <------------------------------------------------------------->
com.keepdynamic.barcode.generator.jasperreports.BarcodeFactory cannot be resolved to a type

value = new com.keepdynamic.barcode.generator.jasperreports.BarcodeRenderer(
com.keepdynamic.barcode.generator.jasperreports.BarcodeFactory.createLinear(
8,"((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRenderable)field_barcode.getOldValue())")); //$JR_EXPR_ID=152$
com.keepdynamic.barcode.generator.jasperreports.BarcodeRenderer cannot
be resolved to a type value = new com.keepdynamic.barcode.generator.jasperreports.BarcodeRenderer(
com.keepdynamic.barcode.generator.jasperreports.BarcodeFactory.createLinear(
8,"((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRenderable)field_barcode.getValue())")); //$JR_EXPR_ID=152$
com.keepdynamic.barcode.generator.jasperreports.BarcodeFactory cannot
be resolved to a type
value = new com.keepdynamic.barcode.generator.jasperreports.BarcodeRenderer(
com.keepdynamic.barcode.generator.jasperreports.BarcodeFactory.createLinear(
8,"((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRenderable)field_barcode.getValue())")); //$JR_EXPR_ID=152$
<------------------------------------------------------------>

errors

at  net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:215)
at net.sf.jasperreports.eclipse.builder.JasperReportCompiler.compileReport(JasperReportCompiler.java:195)
at net.sf.jasperreports.eclipse.builder.JasperReportCompiler.compileReport(JasperReportCompiler.java:91)
at net.sf.jasperreports.eclipse.builder.JasperReportsBuilder.compileJRXML(JasperReportsBuilder.java:211)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.action.CompileAction.actionCompile(CompileAction.java:176)

at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.action.CompileAction$3.run(CompileAction.java:132)

at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Comment: Are you still having problem with this?

Comment: I have already added. Still i get the same error

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the KeepDynamic `barcode.jar` to your classpath

To download the jar visit [their page](http://www.keepdynamic.com/barcoding/barcode-ireport.shtml), however you can consider that other barcode libraries are already included in the jasper distribution as [barbecue](http://barbecue.sourceforge.net/) and [barcode4j](http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/) and these can also be used directly in IDE

Comment: thanks  , im use the barbecue im dawnload jar from this link 
,
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/b/Downloadbarbecue15beta1jar.htm
.